# How do I make my rigged model game ready?

Tags: rigging, export

I''ve created a simple model with only 4 bones as a proof of concept to test my game engine project that Ive been working on. Im wondering what settings are important for exporting animations for 3d games. I exported the model from Blender as a gltf binary (glb), and I know that this incorrect loading of the model might be due to a mistake in my programming but I would like to know for sure that there's nothing I'm doing wrong when exporting/creating the model in Blender.

When I load the model in my program I get this:

[image]

But it looks like this in blender:

[image]

My program has no problem loading models that don't use bones and I did triangulate in blender before baking so I can rule this out. I'd like to know more about what could be going wrong and what pitfalls to avoid when creating models for 3d games in general.

Comment: Do you use shape keys on that model?

Comment: It seems like your bones are simply not in the same position.

Comment: No, I don't use shape keys in fact ive never heard of them. Could this be due to floating point imprecision? Cause it's very similar to what shows up in blender to the point where the difference might just be due to floating point error...